# Azure Databricks externalize metastore - MSFT Script not running

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

I am trying to set up azure databricks with external hive metastore on AzureSQL.
While doing the setup, I created Azure SQL. And now I have to run a MSFT given sql [script](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/metastore/scripts/upgrade/mssql/hive-schema-2.3.0.mssql.sql) which has table and indices creation sql.

When I ran it was able to create new tables but failed in Index creation. I have full access on Database. May be some grant is missing. Also why MSFT or Databrick has such lengthy process?

OR if there a better way to externalize metedata.Please help.

Comment: Amit, can you share the exact error that you see ?

Answer (score 0):

To set up an external metastore using the Azure Databricks UI: Checkout [Set up an external metastore using the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore#set-up-an-external-metastore-using-the-ui)

1. Click the  **Clusters**  button on the sidebar.
2. Click  **Create Cluster**.
3. Enter the following  [Spark configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#spark-config):

   ```
   # Hive-specific configuration options.
   # spark.hadoop prefix is added to make sure these Hive specific options propagate to the metastore client.
   # JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore
   spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL <mssql-connection-string>

   # Username to use against metastore database
   spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName <mssql-username>

   # Password to use against metastore database
   spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword <mssql-password>

   # Driver class name for a JDBC metastore
   spark.hadoop.javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

   # Spark specific configuration options
   spark.sql.hive.metastore.version <hive-version>
   # Skip this one if <hive-version> is 0.13.x.
   spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars <hive-jar-source>
   ```
4. Continue your cluster configuration, following the instructions in  [Configure clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#cluster-configurations).
5. Click  **Create Cluster**  to create the cluster.